# Android How do you save an image with your own unique Image Name?

Tags: android, image

This sounds like a issue a beginner like me would only have...this is my code...

```
    private void saveAvatar(Bitmap avatar) {
    String strAvatarFilename =  Id + ".jpg"; 
    try {
        avatar.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, openFileOutput(strAvatarFilename, MODE_PRIVATE));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Avatar compression and save failed.", e);
    }
    Uri imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo = Uri.fromFile(new File(PhotoActivity.this.getFilesDir(), strAvatarFilename));
    Editor editor = Preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(PREFERENCES_AVATAR, imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo.getPath());
    editor.commit();
    ImageButton avatarButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton_Avatar);
    String strAvatarUri = Preferences.getString(PREFERENCES_AVATAR, "");
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(strAvatarUri);
    avatarButton.setImageURI(null); 
    avatarButton.setImageURI(imageUri);
}
```

This does save the image but when i go to look at the image on the sd card ti is called imag001 etc not the ID i am labelling it. How do i save the image with a name i want to call it? regards

**EDIT**

I found out something interesting...I believe on the SD card in the DCIM/100MEDIA the image taken by the application is stored using the name the phone has set as default. However, under data/data/com.andorid.packagename/files/   the image mayalso is being stored with the name i give to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ostensibly, it seems as if you're setting the filename with the second line of code:

```
String strAvatarFilename =  Id + ".jpg";
```

I don't know where Id is coming from, you haven't included enough context for that, but it seems reasonable that it contains 'imag001'. To name your image something else, you need some other way to set that value. That could look hundreds of different ways.

Comment: Still doesnt work, even if i dont use Id and i just type in my own image name "exampleimage.jpg" it still calls it IMAG0012

Comment: Going to need to see what that change actually looks like in your code to figure out why.

Comment: I would continue by inspecting the value of Uri.getPath(). Perhaps it's only returning the directory path and not the filename? I'm at work and don't have an Android stack or I'd try it myself.

Comment: cheers it was saving it to a file within the application aswell as in the default gallery location

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is looking fine, except one thing. The firstLine of the function. You never pass any id to this function so it use a global class variable (I guess so).

To solve your problem, you should change your function to something like that,

```
private void saveAvatar(String id, Bitmap avatar) {
    String strAvatarFilename =  id + ".jpg";
    ...
}
```

That way you always know where exactly does the id come from. In your current code, it's unclear where you get that Id and if it's even modified anywhere.

Comment: Still doesnt work, even if i dont use Id and i just type in my own image name "exampleimage.jpg" it still calls it IMAG0012

Comment: String strAvatarFilename =  Id + ".jpg";  You had to change that line to use the parameter. id